# Migrating xunit project with FluentAssertions API 4.x syntax to run using FluentAssertions v5.x version

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

I know that there is a breaking change from [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) v4.x to v5.x in [Redefining equivalency](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html)
So, I should modify:

```
        ShouldBeEquivalenTo ()
```

to

```
         Should().BeEquivalentTo()
```

and  a lot more has changed.

I have xunit test project target net45 and start to migrate to multi-target netcoreapp2.1 and net45.(FluentAssertions v4.x isn't supporting netcoreapp2.x)

The project has  many  test cases that use old syntax of 4.x and I want to minimize the changes in the test project and avoid(if i can) modifying to the new syntax.

My options are:

First: I should modify by hand the test cases to support the new syntax of v5.x

Second: you may suggest be an alternative.

Can you advice me to the best path to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally used the RegEx search-and-replace that Visual Studio offers to make this happen.

Comment: Thanks @dennis Doomen for answer. Is there any change in the signature of the methods.?

Comment: I also came yo conclusion that search replace was the simplest most efficient option.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, i want to be sure that there is no change in the signature of the methods. Are you sure that the parameters of the methods are not changing?

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, FA introduces quite a few breaking changes, most dominantly making sure that every API starts with `Should()`, But I've converted about 20K tests using search replace. Since I'm the author....

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the answer of [@Dennis Doomen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115838/3142139)

I used Find/Replace Regex in VS2017:

```
   Find:  Should(\w+)
   Replace: Should().$1
```

This regex replace expressions:

`ShouldBeEquivalentTo, ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo, 
ShouldThrow and ShouldNotThrow`